# how to attach a BytesIO object to a Webob.Response Object

Tags: python, webob, bytesio

I'm returning a Webob.Response object from my server to http request. The server puts together a BytesIO object. How can I correctly attach the BytesIO object to the Webob.Response object?

I tried:

```
app_iter = FileIter(BytesIO_Object)
return Response(
                app_iter=app_iter,
                last_modified=last_modified,
                content_length=content_length,
                content_type=content_type,
                content_encoding=content_encoding,
                content_disposition=content_disposition,
                accept_ranges=accept_ranges,
                conditional_response=True)
```

no luck, when I print `response.content` on the client side, its just empty

I also tried:

```
return Response(self.file, '200 ok', content_type='text/html')
```

but that throws an error:

> File "/home/abdul/abdul/scripting-120218/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webob/response.py", line 147, in **init**
>       self._headerlist.append(('Content-Length', str(len(body))))
>   TypeError: object of type '_io.BytesIO' has no len()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok finally figured it out. You can to pass this to FileIter

```
app_iter = FileIter(BytesIO_Object.read())
```